# (node:11464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The geckodriver.exe executable could not be found on the current PATH

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I use node.js to run the selenium-webdriver and I want to use geckodriver to execute firefox as my testing browser. I have put my geckodriver.exe path into environment variable...

[image]

... but still get the same error.

> (node:11464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The geckodriver.exe executable could not be found on the current PATH.

Here is my simple code.

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver')

async function myFunction() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build()
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com')
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have left filename as it was downloaded. Please rename `geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64 (1).exe` to `geckodriver.exe` and make sure that `C:\Selenium` is in `PATH`.